# Is there a keyboard shortcut for the "Done" button in Adobe Camera Raw"

Tags: adobe-bridge, adobe-camera-raw

When cropping a large number of images in Adobe Bridge via Camera Raw, it would be a great time saver to map a keyboard shortcut to the `Done` button in lower right corner.

The <kbd>Enter</kbd> (Return⁣ – on a Mac) key closes the Camera Raw window, but it also opens the image in Adobe Photoshop, which is not desirable.

Is there a way to only close the window, just instead of clicking the `Done` Button?

[image: Camera raw done button]